# Sort Parse collection in ascending order by value of class column

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, parse-server

I would like to query a class, Inventory, wherein the objects contained have a column called "groupNumber". This groupNumber assigns each of the Inventory objects to a group, naturally. The idea then is to sort this list according to group number, where the first Inventory object with groupNumber 1 will be at the top of the list, the second will be below it, then the first Inventory objects of groupNumber 2, etc.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> inventoryQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Inventory");
inventoryQuery.orderByAscending("groupNumber");
```

Example Data:

```
Inventory object - groupNumber
Item1 - 1
Item6 - 1
Item10 - 1
Item4 - 2
Item5 -2
Item8 - 3
Item2 - 3
Item7 - 4
Item9 - 5
Item3 - 5
```

Can I sort this in the same that I can sort by `createdAt`, for example?

Comment: Do you mean sort it by createdAt? inventoryQuery.ascending("createdAt");
Or you want sort by group number then createdAt? (if equal, sort by createdAt) 
inventoryQuery.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")

Comment: Yes, first sort by groupNumber (each Inventory object is assigned one), then by createdAt. I updated it above to reflect proper Java implementation.

Comment: How will it know to sort by ascending order in the groupNumber column? Does it do this automatically?

Comment: Are you aware that parse.com will close on January 2017? See http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Yes I am aware, but this doesn't make it less relevant. I'm currently hosting parse-server with DocumentDB on Microsoft Azure. It's not going away any less than WordPress, as an open source platform, likely ever will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> inventoryQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Inventory");
inventoryQuery.addAscendingOrder("groupNumber");
inventoryQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
```

it will sort "groupNumber" by ascending, then sort "createdAt"

priority depends on the order you use "addXXXXOrder".